# How to reset a label in a CustomObjectTranslation back to its original value using the Ant Migration Tool?

Tags: ant, xml, translation, translation-workbench

I use a Case object with a custom field having an API Name of `ExampleField__c` and a Label of `Example Field`.

Lets say I have a translation file for a `Case` object and there's a section for the `Example Field`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomObjectTranslation xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    ...
    <fields>
        <label>My Example Field Translation</label>
        <name>ExampleField__c</name>
    </fields>
    ...
</CustomObjectTranslation>
```

For some reason I wanted to go back with the `<label>` value to field's original label, in this case from "My Example Field Translation" back to "Example Field". How can I do that using the Ant Migration Tool?

I tried removing the text between the `<label>` markup, but after the deploy nothing changed at all and retrieving translations again gave me the same old value.